# MutableLiveData wrong value when accessing directly

Tags: android, android-mvvm

I have ViewModel:

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
var connected = MutableLiveData(false)

fun setConnected(value: Boolean) {
    connected.postValue(value)
 }
}
```

When setting value:

```
viewModel.setConnected(true)
```

And then observing it like so:

```
viewModel.connected.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
Log.d(RTAG, "Connected: $it")
})
```

It works as expected. But sometimes I need acess the value directly and not observing the change like so:

```
 viewModel.setConnected(true)
 Log.d(RTAG, "Res: "+viewModel.connected.value) //printed old result, why?
```

Then I get old result, why is that?

Comment: postValue method doesn't change the value immediately. It should be used in a background thread. Try using setValue which should be invoked only on main thread.

Comment: @JudeOsbertK Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postValue` method doesn't change the value immediately. It should be used in a background thread. Try using `setValue` which should be invoked only on main thread and sets the value immediately.